# Почему Disk sda utilization показывает больше 100%?

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, zabbix

Систематически метрика "Disk sda utilization" на графике в zabbix поднимается больше 100% (например, 2200% и т.п.), что невозможно. Была догадка насчет параметра timeout в конфиге заббикс агента, поставил timeout = 30, но не помогло
Используется на машине CentOS 7
HDD_iostat.sh находится в /etc/zabbix/zabbix_scripts/

Comment: Очевидно, что из рассчёта на одну очередь, а их несколько. Или что-то в этом духе.